# pip install seems to be ignoring dependency links

Tags: python, pip

I have a Python application that depends on several packages.  One of those packages, unfortunately, isn't in PyPi so I have to install it directly from the git repo.

I've been trying to add it into my setup.py like so:

```
setup(
..,
..,
dependency_links = [
                 'https://github.com/marcuz/libpynexmo.git#egg=nexmomessage'
    ],
install_requires=[
    ..,
    'nexmomessage'
],
packages=['localpackage']
```

However it fails: No distributions at all found for nexmomessage

I see where it creates the dependency links list: writing dependency_links to common.egg-info/dependency_links.txt - and when I look at that file the URL is correct.

If I run it at command line: pip install -e git+https://github.com/marcuz/libpynexmo.git#egg=nexmomessage

It installs without an issue.

Thoughts?

Comment: What version of `pip` are you using?

Comment: pip 1.5.6 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of pip 1.5, [dependency links are deprecated](https://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/news.html). Currently pip can still be forced to be used them with the `--process-dependency-links` flag. You might also have to use `--allow-external packagename` or `--allow-unverified packagename`, where `packagename` actually specifies whichever dependency  you want to install that's not in an official repository

Note that since it's deprecated functionality, the `--process-dependency-links` flag will be completely removed soon. I believe the preferred approach is to supply a `requirements.txt` file.

Comment: Indeed, this was the conclusion I came to in September as well.  Though it was odd that it was able to run from command line without the flags, but not in the setup.py.  In the end I contacted the author and made a heartfelt plea he get his packages up to pypi to make life easier :)

Comment: According to the 1.5 release-notes, dependency links are not "deprecated" - it is the `--process-dependency-links` that is needed to process them.  Additionally, since 8.0.0, you may add this option in a new line in requirements-file, so that the user does not have to type it in the command-line (see [pip#1274](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1274).

Answer (score 2):

And as of pip 7 they are enabled again. This means you can now use `dependency_links` using pip:

`pip install -e /path/to/python/module --process-dependency-links --allow-all-external`

If you'r using your distros system pip you might need to upgrade pip:

`pip install pip --upgrade`

Appears to have happened in pull request [#1519](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/1955)

Comment: Aand in pip `pip 9.0.1` when I do this I get `DEPRECATION: --allow-all-external has been deprecated and will be removed in the future. Due to changes in the repository protocol, it no longer has any effect.` and `DEPRECATION: Dependency Links processing has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release.`